# DISCORD BOT : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permission')`

Tags: discord.js

Its been a while since I programmed the Permissions Handler which all the perms will be handled each command. So I'm using Discord.Js v14 and it seems that this Permission handling is "deprecated"??? I really don't know so the error is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permission')`

and here is my code

```
const ValidPerms = [
    p.AddReactions,
    p.Administrator,
    p.AttachFiles,
    p.BanMembers,
    p.ChangeNickname,
    p.Connect,
    p.CreateInstantInvite,
    p.CreatePrivateThreads,
    p.CreatePublicThreads,
    p.DeafenMembers,
    p.EmbedLinks,
    p.KickMembers,
    p.ManageChannels,
    p.ManageEmojisAndStickers,
    p.ManageEvents,
    p.ManageGuild,
    p.ManageMessages,
    p.ManageNicknames,
    p.ManageRoles,
    p.ManageThreads,
    p.ManageWebhooks,
    p.MentionEveryone,
    p.ModerateMembers,
    p.MoveMembers,  
    p.MuteMembers,
    p.PrioritySpeaker,
    p.ReadMessageHistory,
    p.RequestToSpeak,
    p.SendMessages,
    p.SendMessagesInThreads,
    p.SendTTSMessages,
    p.Speak,
    p.Stream,
    p.UseApplicationCommands,
    p.UseEmbeddedActivities,
    p.UseExternalEmojis,
    p.UseExternalStickers,
    p.UseVAD,
    p.ViewAuditLog,
    p.ViewChannel,
    p.ViewGuildInsights,
]


if (command.permissions) {
    let invalidPerms = []
    for (const permission of command.permissions) {
        if (!ValidPerms.includes(permission)) {
            console.log(`Invalid Perms`)
        }

        if (!message.members.permission.has(permission)) {
            invalidPerms.push(permission)
        }
    }

    if (invalidPerms.length) {
        const noPermsEmbed = new ME()
            .setColor(config.colors.no)
            .setTitle("Aww~~~ You dont have have permss~")
            .addField('Aweee~~~ you don\'t have permissions to run command:', `\`${command.name}\``)
            .addField('Permission Required', `\`${invalidPerms}\``)
            .setFooter({ text : client.user.username, iconURL : client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
            .setTimestamp()

        return message.channel.send(noPermsEmbed);
    }
}
```

I tried using the "ADMINISTRATOR" like putting something like this in one like in the code and still the same error where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I fixed it I have so many errors on creating the perms I didn't read the docs of so I fixed it by changing the `p.[perms]` to `p.Flags.[perms]` and I forgot to create a new function called :

```
`const ValidPerms = new PermissionsBitField(perms)`
```

and I fixed this function as well :

```
if (command.permissions) {
    let invalidPerms = []
    for (const permission1 of command.permissions) {
        if (!ValidPerms.has(permission1)) {
            console.log(`Invalid Perms`)
        }

        const member = message.member

        if (!member.permissions.has(permission1)) {
            invalidPerms.push(permission1)
        }
    }

    if (invalidPerms.length) {
        const noPermsEmbed = new ME()
            .setColor('Random')
            .setTitle("Aww~~~ You dont have have permss~")
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: 'Aweee~~~ you don\'t have permissions to run command:',
                    value: `\`${command.name}\``
                }
            )
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: 'Permission Required',
                    value: `\`${invalidPerms}\``
                }
            )
            .setFooter({ text: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
            .setTimestamp()

        return message.channel.send({embeds : [noPermsEmbed]});
    }
}
```

and on the command as well *On Module.Exports* :

```
permissions: ['BanMembers'],
```

I hope this answer will help you as well

reference here : https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#converting-permission-numbers